# Calling of methods in ios

Tags: ios

I am very new to ios and having a problem to call four different methods one after the other, as I would like to call them after comparison like if(number<6)

method2->method3->method4->method1-> such that it would make a loop until the comparison of (number)become false.

Also I want method1 to be activated in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Please explain more briefly

Comment: Just google, Before ask question here.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should make a serious atempt at solving the problem at hand before you ask it as question here. And if you already have done that: Then you should show us what you've done so far...

Answer (score 0):

use `[self method1];` somewhere else and use as follows:

```
-(void) method1
{
    [self method2];
}
-(void) method2
{
    [self method3];
}
-(void) method3
{
    [self method4];
}
-(void) method4
{
    // do if you need.
}
```

Or Try `NSNotificationCenter`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, if I understood your question properly

```
[[[method2 method3] method4] method1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`[yourObject performSelector:@selector(method1:)]`

You can call it on any NSObject (and subclasses of course). You may want to try before :

`[yourObject respondToSelector:@selector(method1:)]`

This will tell you if your object has this method or not (avoid exceptions and errors).

[More informations on the official documentation of performSelector](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/performSelector%3a).

Answer (score 0):

I hope i'm interpreting your question correctly. But here's a simple implementation...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self method1];
}

- (void)method1 {
    /* do stuff */
    [self method2];
}

- (void)method2 {
    /* do stuff */
    [self method3];
}

- (void)method3 {
    /* do stuff */
    [self method4];
}

- (void)method4 {
    /* do stuff */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
-(void) method1
{
    if (number<6)
    {
        [self method2];
    }
}

-(void) method2
{
    [self method3];
}

-(void) method3
{
     [self method4];
}

-(void) method4
{
    [self method1];
}
```